# Importing java classes in Intellij Kotlin app

Tags: java, kotlin, intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJ for the first time to write a Kotlin program for windows.

I need to read a file so I used code from a sample site:

```
import java.io.File
import java.io.InputStream

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
  val inputStream: InputStream = File("bezkoder.txt").inputStream()
  val lineList = mutableListOf<String>()

  inputStream.bufferedReader().useLines { lines -> lines.forEach { lineList.add(it)} }
  lineList.forEach{println(">  " + it)}
}
```

The thing is that it doesn't recognise the import for the java classes.

I guess it is something in my setup but I have no idea where to look and haven't managed to find an answer.

This is my SDK setup screen

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use Java SDK classes in the Kotlin/Native projects, only in Kotlin/JVM.

Please also make sure you have a valid JDK configuration in the project. [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61180376/104891) for more details.

If you want to read a file in Kotlin Native, see [CsvParser.kt](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-native/blob/master/samples/csvparser/src/csvParserMain/kotlin/CsvParser.kt) example.

Comment: Thanks. My setup seems to be okay. I have updated my question with the configuration screen

Comment: Please try File | Invalidate Caches | Invalidate and Restart. I [can't reproduce the issue](https://i.imgur.com/Aziv4MI.png). Double check project and module is set to use the same JDK configuration.

Comment: I looked at you link and the one big difference I see is I don't have the KotlinJavaRuntime libraries. I am using KotlinNative - could that be the problem? I have added an image showing what I see.

Comment: Yes, you can't use Java classes in Native projects.

Comment: See https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-native/blob/master/samples/csvparser/src/csvParserMain/kotlin/CsvParser.kt.