# Android Studio: unresolved reference for java and javax imports, but project compiles

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, gradle

I am trying to create my own Annotation processor in Android Studio project.

**I've created another module for that in Android Studio**.

I am able to compile the project. I can't just use autocomplete and other stuff. IDE treat all the references as unresolved references error in that case

[image]

How can I resolve this issue?

**WHAT IS IMPORTANT**

When I created new libary module "autoadapter-process" by default Android Studio created it with this implementation in build.gradle for this module:

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
```

To be able to compile the project I replaced it to:

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
```

Below is my JDK setup in Project Structure (Android Studio):
[image]

Below is my project structure:

[image]

And here is my Gradle configuration for autoadapter-processor module:

```
apply plugin: 'java-library'
apply plugin: 'kotlin'

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation project(':autoadapter-annotations')
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
}
```

**This** https://stackoverflow.com/a/61180376/104891 **problem is not similiar to mine, as it is IntelliJ IDEA specifc. It is not Android Studio specific**.

Answer (score 2):

It seems, that Android Studio cache some previous settings imported for the new Android Studio version. I was doing it pretty much for long time when updating probably from versions 3.1 -> 3.2 -> 3.4 -> ... -> 4.0

So the old JDK version seemed to be cached inside **jdk.table.xml** file

You can find this file inside whenever your Android Studio options folder is located (in my case it was User/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio4.0/options)

You can either delete it and let it be created again with proper versions (which worked for me and is the solution for my problem:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/38067170/5434346

Or you can try to modify it (I did not tried that): https://stackoverflow.com/a/41531367/5434346

What is strange it did not contained any JDK 1.7 references:

```
<application>
  <component name="ProjectJdkTable">
    <jdk version="2">
      <name value="1.8" />
      <type value="JavaSDK" />
      <version value="java version &quot;1.8.0_152-release&quot;" />
      <homePath value="$APPLICATION_HOME_DIR$/jre/jdk/Contents/Home" />
      <roots>
        <annotationsPath>
          <root type="composite">
            <root url="jar:///private/var/folders/b2/cyvk3_yx2g79yctwzx_l7lx80000gn/T/AppTranslocation/2A3A91C1-D3F4-4B90-9B20-E2C1047BDD8F/d/Android Studio 3.5.app/Contents/lib/jdkAnnotations.jar!/" type="simple" />
          </root>
        </annotationsPath>
        <classPath>
          <root type="composite">
            <root url="jar:///private/var/folders/b2/cyvk3_yx2g79yctwzx_l7lx80000gn/T/AppTranslocation/2A3A91C1-D3F4-4B90-9B20-E2C1047BDD8F/d/Android Studio 3.5.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/charsets.jar!/" type="simple" />
            <root url="jar:///private/var/folders/b2/cyvk3_yx2g79yctwzx_l7lx80000gn/T/AppTranslocation/2A3A91C1-D3F4-4B90-9B20-E2C1047BDD8F/d/Android Studio 3.5.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar!/" type="simple" />
            <root url="jar:///private/var/folders/b2/cyvk3_yx2g79yctwzx_l7lx80000gn/T/AppTranslocation/2A3A91C1-D3F4-4B90-9B20-E2C1047BDD8F/d/Android Studio 3.5.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar!/" type="simple" />
            <root url="jar:///private/var/folders/b2/cyvk3_yx2g79yctwzx_l7lx80000gn/T/AppTranslocation/2A3A91C1-D3F4-4B90-9B20-E2C1047BDD8F/d/Android Studio 3.5.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/jaccess.jar!/" type="simple" />
            <root url="jar:///private/var/folders/b2/cyvk3_yx2g79yctwzx_l7lx80000gn/T/AppTranslocation/2A3A91C1-D3F4-4B90-9B20-E2C1047BDD8F/d/Android Studio 3.5.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar!/" type="simple" />
            <root url="jar:///private/var/folders/b2/cyvk3_yx2g79yctwzx_l7lx80000gn/T/AppTranslocation/2A3A91C1-D3F4-4B90-9B20-E2C1047BDD8F/d/Android Studio 3.5.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar!/" type="simple" />
            <root url="jar:///private/var/folders/b2/cyvk3_yx2g79yctwzx_l7lx80000gn/T/AppTranslocation/2A3A91C1-D3F4-4B90-9B20-E2C1047BDD8F/d/Android Studio 3.5.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar!/" type="simple" />
            <root url="jar:///private/var/folders/b2/cyvk3_yx2g79yctwzx_l7lx80000gn/T/AppTranslocation/2A3A91C1-D3F4-4B90-9B20-E2C1047BDD8F/d/Android Studio 3.5.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar!/" type="simple" />
            <root url="jar:///private/var/folders/b2/cyvk3_yx2g79yctwzx_l7lx80000gn/T/AppTranslocation/2A3A91C1-D3F4-4B90-9B20-E2C1047BDD8F/d/Android Studio 3.5.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar!/" type="simple" />
            <root url="jar:///private/var/folders/b2/cyvk3_yx2g79yctwzx_l7lx80000gn/T/AppTranslocation/2A3A91C1-D3F4-4B90-9B20-E2C1047BDD8F/d/Android Studio 3.5.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar!/" type="simple" />
            <root url="jar:///private/var/folders/b2/cyvk3_yx2g79yctwzx_l7lx80000gn/T/AppTranslocation/2A3A91C1-D3F4-4B90-9B20-E2C1047BDD8F/d/Android Studio 3.5.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jce.jar!/" type="simple" />
            <root url="jar:///private/var/folders/b2/cyvk3_yx2g79yctwzx_l7lx80000gn/T/AppTranslocation/2A3A91C1-D3F4-4B90-9B20-E2C1047BDD8F/d/Android Studio 3.5.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jsse.jar!/" type="simple" />
            <root url="jar:///private/var/folders/b2/cyvk3_yx2g79yctwzx_l7lx80000gn/T/AppTranslocation/2A3A91C1-D3F4-4B90-9B20-E2C1047BDD8F/d/Android Studio 3.5.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/management-agent.jar!/" type="simple" />
            <root url="jar:///private/var/folders/b2/cyvk3_yx2g79yctwzx_l7lx80000gn/T/AppTranslocation/2A3A91C1-D3F4-4B90-9B20-E2C1047BDD8F/d/Android Studio 3.5.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/resources.jar!/" type="simple" />
            <root url="jar:///private/var/folders/b2/cyvk3_yx2g79yctwzx_l7lx80000gn/T/AppTranslocation/2A3A91C1-D3F4-4B90-9B20-E2C1047BDD8F/d/Android Studio 3.5.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar!/" type="simple" />
            <root url="jar:///private/var/folders/b2/cyvk3_yx2g79yctwzx_l7lx80000gn/T/AppTranslocation/2A3A91C1-D3F4-4B90-9B20-E2C1047BDD8F/d/Android Studio 3.5.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/lib/dt.jar!/" type="simple" />
            <root url="jar:///private/var/folders/b2/cyvk3_yx2g79yctwzx_l7lx80000gn/T/AppTranslocation/2A3A91C1-D3F4-4B90-9B20-E2C1047BDD8F/d/Android Studio 3.5.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/lib/jconsole.jar!/" type="simple" />
            <root url="jar:///private/var/folders/b2/cyvk3_yx2g79yctwzx_l7lx80000gn/T/AppTranslocation/2A3A91C1-D3F4-4B90-9B20-E2C1047BDD8F/d/Android Studio 3.5.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/lib/sa-jdi.jar!/" type="simple" />
            <root url="jar:///private/var/folders/b2/cyvk3_yx2g79yctwzx_l7lx80000gn/T/AppTranslocation/2A3A91C1-D3F4-4B90-9B20-E2C1047BDD8F/d/Android Studio 3.5.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/lib/tools.jar!/" type="simple" />
          </root>
        </classPath>
        <javadocPath>
          <root type="composite">
            <root url="http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/" type="simple" />
          </root>
        </javadocPath>
        <sourcePath>
          <root type="composite" />
        </sourcePath>
      </roots>
      <additional />
    </jdk>
    <jdk version="2">
      <name value="Android API 27 Platform" />
      <type value="Android SDK" />
      <version value="java version &quot;1.8.0_152-release&quot;" />
      <homePath value="$USER_HOME$/Library/Android/sdk" />
      <roots>
        <annotationsPath>
          <root type="composite">
            <root url="jar:///private/var/folders/b2/cyvk3_yx2g79yctwzx_l7lx80000gn/T/AppTranslocation/2A3A91C1-D3F4-4B90-9B20-E2C1047BDD8F/d/Android Studio 3.5.app/Contents/plugins/android/lib/androidAnnotations.jar!/" type="simple" />
          </root>
        </annotationsPath>
        <classPath>
          <root type="composite">
            <root url="jar://$USER_HOME$/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-27/android.jar!/" type="simple" />
            <root url="file://$USER_HOME$/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-27/data/res" type="simple" />
          </root>
        </classPath>
        <javadocPath>
          <root type="composite">
            <root url="http://developer.android.com/reference/" type="simple" />
          </root>
        </javadocPath>
        <sourcePath>
          <root type="composite" />
        </sourcePath>
      </roots>
      <additional jdk="1.8" sdk="android-27" />
    </jdk>
    <jdk version="2">
      <name value="Android API 25 Platform" />
      <type value="Android SDK" />
      <version value="java version &quot;1.8.0_152-release&quot;" />
      <homePath value="$USER_HOME$/Library/Android/sdk" />
      <roots>
        <annotationsPath>
          <root type="composite">
            <root url="jar:///private/var/folders/b2/cyvk3_yx2g79yctwzx_l7lx80000gn/T/AppTranslocation/2A3A91C1-D3F4-4B90-9B20-E2C1047BDD8F/d/Android Studio 3.5.app/Contents/plugins/android/lib/androidAnnotations.jar!/" type="simple" />
          </root>
        </annotationsPath>
        <classPath>
          <root type="composite">
            <root url="jar://$USER_HOME$/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-25/android.jar!/" type="simple" />
            <root url="file://$USER_HOME$/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-25/data/res" type="simple" />
          </root>
        </classPath>
        <javadocPath>
          <root type="composite">
            <root url="http://developer.android.com/reference/" type="simple" />
          </root>
        </javadocPath>
        <sourcePath>
          <root type="composite" />
        </sourcePath>
      </roots>
      <additional jdk="1.8" sdk="android-25" />
    </jdk>
    <jdk version="2">
      <name value="Android API 26 Platform" />
      <type value="Android SDK" />
      <version value="java version &quot;1.8.0_152-release&quot;" />
      <homePath value="$USER_HOME$/Library/Android/sdk" />
      <roots>
        <annotationsPath>
          <root type="composite">
            <root url="jar://$APPLICATION_HOME_DIR$/plugins/android/lib/androidAnnotations.jar!/" type="simple" />
          </root>
        </annotationsPath>
        <classPath>
          <root type="composite">
            <root url="jar://$USER_HOME$/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-26/android.jar!/" type="simple" />
            <root url="file://$USER_HOME$/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-26/data/res" type="simple" />
          </root>
        </classPath>
        <javadocPath>
          <root type="composite" />
        </javadocPath>
        <sourcePath>
          <root type="composite">
            <root url="file://$USER_HOME$/Library/Android/sdk/sources/android-26" type="simple" />
          </root>
        </sourcePath>
      </roots>
      <additional jdk="1.8" sdk="android-26" />
    </jdk>
    <jdk version="2">
      <name value="Android API 23 Platform" />
      <type value="Android SDK" />
      <version value="java version &quot;1.8.0_152-release&quot;" />
      <homePath value="$USER_HOME$/Library/Android/sdk" />
      <roots>
        <annotationsPath>
          <root type="composite">
            <root url="jar:///private/var/folders/b2/cyvk3_yx2g79yctwzx_l7lx80000gn/T/AppTranslocation/2A3A91C1-D3F4-4B90-9B20-E2C1047BDD8F/d/Android Studio 3.5.app/Contents/plugins/android/lib/androidAnnotations.jar!/" type="simple" />
          </root>
        </annotationsPath>
        <classPath>
          <root type="composite">
            <root url="jar://$USER_HOME$/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-23/android.jar!/" type="simple" />
            <root url="file://$USER_HOME$/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-23/data/res" type="simple" />
          </root>
        </classPath>
        <javadocPath>
          <root type="composite">
            <root url="http://developer.android.com/reference/" type="simple" />
          </root>
        </javadocPath>
        <sourcePath>
          <root type="composite" />
        </sourcePath>
      </roots>
      <additional jdk="1.8" sdk="android-23" />
    </jdk>
    <jdk version="2">
      <name value="Android API 28 Platform" />
      <type value="Android SDK" />
      <version value="java version &quot;1.8.0_152-release&quot;" />
      <homePath value="$USER_HOME$/Library/Android/sdk" />
      <roots>
        <annotationsPath>
          <root type="composite">
            <root url="jar://$USER_HOME$/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-28/data/annotations.zip!/" type="simple" />
          </root>
        </annotationsPath>
        <classPath>
          <root type="composite">
            <root url="jar://$USER_HOME$/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-28/android.jar!/" type="simple" />
            <root url="file://$USER_HOME$/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-28/data/res" type="simple" />
          </root>
        </classPath>
        <javadocPath>
          <root type="composite">
            <root url="http://developer.android.com/reference/" type="simple" />
          </root>
        </javadocPath>
        <sourcePath>
          <root type="composite" />
        </sourcePath>
      </roots>
      <additional jdk="1.8" sdk="android-28" />
    </jdk>
    <jdk version="2">
      <name value="Kotlin SDK" />
      <type value="KotlinSDK" />
      <version value="1.3.30" />
      <homePath value="$USER_HOME$/Library/Application Support/AndroidStudio3.6/Kotlin/kotlinc" />
      <roots>
        <annotationsPath>
          <root type="composite" />
        </annotationsPath>
        <classPath>
          <root type="composite" />
        </classPath>
        <javadocPath>
          <root type="composite" />
        </javadocPath>
        <sourcePath>
          <root type="composite" />
        </sourcePath>
      </roots>
      <additional />
    </jdk>
    <jdk version="2">
      <name value="Android API 29 Platform" />
      <type value="Android SDK" />
      <version value="java version &quot;1.8.0_152-release&quot;" />
      <homePath value="$USER_HOME$/Library/Android/sdk" />
      <roots>
        <annotationsPath>
          <root type="composite">
            <root url="jar://$APPLICATION_HOME_DIR$/plugins/android/lib/androidAnnotations.jar!/" type="simple" />
          </root>
        </annotationsPath>
        <classPath>
          <root type="composite">
            <root url="jar://$USER_HOME$/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-29/android.jar!/" type="simple" />
            <root url="file://$USER_HOME$/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-29/data/res" type="simple" />
          </root>
        </classPath>
        <javadocPath>
          <root type="composite">
            <root url="http://developer.android.com/reference/" type="simple" />
          </root>
        </javadocPath>
        <sourcePath>
          <root type="composite" />
        </sourcePath>
      </roots>
      <additional jdk="1.8" sdk="android-29" />
    </jdk>
    <jdk version="2">
      <name value="1.8.0_161" />
      <type value="JavaSDK" />
      <version value="java version &quot;1.8.0_161&quot;" />
      <homePath value="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home" />
      <roots>
        <annotationsPath>
          <root type="composite">
            <root url="jar://$APPLICATION_HOME_DIR$/lib/jdkAnnotations.jar!/" type="simple" />
          </root>
        </annotationsPath>
        <classPath>
          <root type="composite">
            <root url="jar:///Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/charsets.jar!/" type="simple" />
            <root url="jar:///Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/deploy.jar!/" type="simple" />
            <root url="jar:///Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar!/" type="simple" />
            <root url="jar:///Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar!/" type="simple" />
            <root url="jar:///Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/jaccess.jar!/" type="simple" />
            <root url="jar:///Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar!/" type="simple" />
            <root url="jar:///Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar!/" type="simple" />
            <root url="jar:///Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar!/" type="simple" />
            <root url="jar:///Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar!/" type="simple" />
            <root url="jar:///Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar!/" type="simple" />
            <root url="jar:///Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar!/" type="simple" />
            <root url="jar:///Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar!/" type="simple" />
            <root url="jar:///Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/javaws.jar!/" type="simple" />
            <root url="jar:///Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jce.jar!/" type="simple" />
            <root url="jar:///Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfr.jar!/" type="simple" />
            <root url="jar:///Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfxswt.jar!/" type="simple" />
            <root url="jar:///Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jsse.jar!/" type="simple" />
            <root url="jar:///Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/management-agent.jar!/" type="simple" />
            <root url="jar:///Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/plugin.jar!/" type="simple" />
            <root url="jar:///Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/resources.jar!/" type="simple" />
            <root url="jar:///Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar!/" type="simple" />
            <root url="jar:///Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/ant-javafx.jar!/" type="simple" />
            <root url="jar:///Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/dt.jar!/" type="simple" />
            <root url="jar:///Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/javafx-mx.jar!/" type="simple" />
            <root url="jar:///Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/jconsole.jar!/" type="simple" />
            <root url="jar:///Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/packager.jar!/" type="simple" />
            <root url="jar:///Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/sa-jdi.jar!/" type="simple" />
            <root url="jar:///Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/tools.jar!/" type="simple" />
          </root>
        </classPath>
        <javadocPath>
          <root type="composite" />
        </javadocPath>
        <sourcePath>
          <root type="composite">
            <root url="jar:///Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/src.zip!/" type="simple" />
            <root url="jar:///Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/javafx-src.zip!/" type="simple" />
          </root>
        </sourcePath>
      </roots>
      <additional />
    </jdk>
  </component>
</application>
```

Anyway, the new file looks like this and now I don't experience my issue (I was not able to post the content straight here due to body limit)
https://pastebin.com/EdDKpZAT

However, when i try to create new module inside my project Android Studio still create the it with I think wrong configuration and JDK7 setup:

```
apply plugin: 'java-library'
apply plugin: 'kotlin'

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}

sourceCompatibility = "1.7"
targetCompatibility = "1.7"
```

But inside that module I am able to import my references to javax