# IntelliJ bundled jdk path

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-14

What is the path to the bundled jdk location in IntelliJ 2020.1?
I have searched JDK in Settings can't find any reference to the path in it.

Comment: You should not use the bundled JDK for your projects, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/61180376/104891. The path is `IDE_HOME\jbr`. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Thanks @CrazyCoder I use my own jdk for compiling my project. The bundled jdk however is used to run plugins etc within the ide itself. I am having problems with a plugin, and need to add a cert to the bundled jdk that is running it.