# Intellij Cannot resolve symbol on import after indexing

Tags: intellij-idea, import

So the problem only occured after Indexing. The reason why I know this is because I tried invalidating the cache and restarting intellij and the import worked like a charm, but then I noticed in the background task Intellij is Indexing. And right after it finished the import doesn't work anymore. Does anybody has a clue about what happened here?

Comment: See if [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61180376/12594975) helps.

Comment: doesnt work for me :(

Comment: Is it reproducible with every project? Could you please attach idea.log ("Help | Show log in...") after reproducing?