# Error with IntelliJ and Gradle, impossible to use the main

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

I followed every single answer of this post [Error: Could not find or load main class in intelliJ IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10654120/error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-in-intellij-ide) but I still can't start my projet.
As you can see on the picture I setted `src` as a source folder using the Project Structure options but still it isn't working.
[image: dd]

I also created an `out` folder and set it in the settings like this :
[image]

but it didn't help, I invalidated the cache and restarded intelliJ and my computer but nothing changed. I'm starting to run out of ideas and I'm really stuck now

Comment: JDK configuration may be broken. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/61180376/104891. Also try https://i.imgur.com/HpeUaUE.png option. If the issue persists see https://stackoverflow.com/a/42660624/104891.

Comment: Thank you for the links, after uninstalling my JDK and downloading them again it worked !