# Why can I not resolve String and System symbols in java Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, intellij-idea

So I recently deleted the -studio64.exe.vmoptions file and the next time I launched it, it's unable to detect common libraries like 'String' and 'System'. I tried to download Jetbrains IDE also, and it throws the same error-

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EV3EV.png

What I have tried so far:

- Change gradle build version
- Reinstall Android studio
- Uninstall Android studio completely- including jdk and sdk dependencies. Upon reinstallation (technically from scratch), the issue still persisted.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: IntelliJ does not have a JDK defined. Download one and assign it to the project.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/61180376/104891.

Comment: @CrazyCoder @ f1sh I see that the solution is for IntelliJ and not Android Studio. General question: Do you prefer coding on IntelliJ or Android Studio? Which one is better in your opinion?

Comment: Android Studio has the same configuration and you tagged your question with #intellij-idea. Choose whatever you like more. It's not the type of questions allowed here.